# Passing a variable from HTML form into mongodb query by POST method using body parser, node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I am sending data from html form to use it in a find query in mongodb but when using it in the query its searching for the variable name instead of the value store in it.

```
app.post('/love',function(req, res){
var article = new Article();
article.headers.Subject = req.body.title;
var x = "article.headers.Subject";
console.log(x);
var query = Article.find({'header.Subject': {$regex: 'x'}}).limit(2);
query.exec(function(err, articles){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.render('index.html',{
            title: 'author',
            articles:articles
        });
    }
});
return;
})
```

Tried all the querying options like:

```
.find('headers.Subject' : /x/i)
.find('headers.Subject': 'x')
```

I have printed x and its getting the value but when its in find query it is just searching for the alphabet "x".

Model structure:

```
var ArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    body: 'String',
    subFolder: 'String',
    headers:{
        Subject: 'String',
        Date: 'Date'
    }
});
```

Comment: change {'header.Subject': {$regex: 'x'}} to {header.Subject: {$regex: /x/i}} and see if it works

Comment: Now the code is not running 
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token "."

Comment: oh it should be headers.Subject

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Problem is not here coz the query is running in my code and the results displayed are for 'x' but not the value in req.body.title

Comment: can you comment these 2 lines : var x = "article.headers.Subject";
console.log(x);

Comment: Already did that using article.heades.Subject directly in query no sucess

Comment: add a jsfiddle so that I can test it there

Comment: let me see never used it before

Comment: try with, var x = "article.$.headers.$.Subject";

Comment: not working @chetanmekha